# What's left of Bones AFTER decomposition?

Tags: death, skeletons, bones

So, after doing a bit of research, I know that Bones decompose in humid conditions and with enough time. However, what do they decompose into? Most people simply say "dust", which works if you only have a few skeletons, but what about a massive amount of skeletons? Thousands, hundreds of thousands, piled up after thousands of years in humid conditions?

I'm aware that Limestone is made of skeletal fragments of marine creatures, but would this happen above ground with human remains? Would it just become dirt? Or is there some other material which would be left over?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see what's the world building part of your question. Looks like you are just asking real life question here.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty much with @Mołot on this one. Could you [Edit] to clarify how this is about building a fictional world? If you're simply looking for real-world facts, then our sister site [biology.se] may be more appropriate for this question as they deal in the matter of real-world biology.

Answer (score 2):

**Basic Component Materials**

Bone is primarily comprised of various collagen compounds and minerals. Collagen makes up about 50% of a bone's wet mass and about 30% of its dry mass. The rest of a bone's mass is comprised of hydroxite, calcium, carbonate, phosphates and hydroxyapatite. Bacteria will over time break down and digest the collagen leaving this crystalline mineral structure behind. Eventually given enough time this mineral structure will break down into finer and finer granules of the same composition. Eventually you would have.... well... a calcium and phosphate rich dust.

Believe it or not this process only takes a few years. In a warm humid environment Bacteria digest the collagen and the minerals in bones are soluble to various acids that can be found in soils at humid locations. Even this bone dust will eventually just be absorbed as mineral components into the soil as well as be absorbed as nutrients by various microorganisms, fungi, and plants. Limestone is not formed from bones, it is formed from mineral deposits left over millions and millions of years in very thin layers from ancient corals and microorganisms. Limestone forms underneath the ocean in shallow clear water and takes geological periods of time to happen.